# retain select option value in php

Tags: php, html-select

```php
<select class="form-control" id="oid">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['id'];?>">
            <?= $row['first_name'];?> #<?= $row['mobileno']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
</select>

<?php
echo $row['id'];
?>
```

i want to echo this select option value in php , it will catch easily in javascript but cant echo in php

Comment: you can't reference `$row` outside of your while loop.

Comment: Not to mention that PHP renders it server side, by the time the client changes it, PHP is done.

Comment: is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

> it will catch easily in javascript but cant echo in php

PHP is a server-side scripting language, which means that in your case you could only echo the option value of the selection after submitting it to the server. Here `echo $row['id'];` will just print the last id fetched from your database.

(Client-side) JS executes in the browser, this allows you to track user selections as they are happening.

```php
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" id="oid" name="userselection">
        <option>--Select--</option>
        <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['id'];?>">
                <?= $row['first_name'];?> #<?= $row['mobileno']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php   
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit selection" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['userselection'];
}
?>
```